what is the problem on my code trying to make graphene layer
variable a equal 2.461
variable a_half equal ${a}/2.0
variable sqrt3 equal sqrt(3)
variable yhi equal ${a_half}*${sqrt3}

lattice custom ${a} &
    a1 1.0 0.0 0.0 &
    a2 0.5 0.86602540378 0.0 &
    a3 0.0 0.0 1.0 &
    basis 0.0 0.0 0.0 &
    basis 0.333333 0.66666666 0.0

region whole prism 0 ${a} 0 ${yhi} 0 1 ${a_half} 0 0
create_box 1 whole
create_atoms 1 region whole

mass 1 12.010700

i'm trying to make one graphene layer using lammps and when i run this code, potential energy is very weird. i mean I am trying to plot the graph of energy versus lattice constant, but I am struggling because it is not forming a parabola.

I'm not all that familiar with LAMMPS, but it looks to me like you are defining the out-of-plane lattice constant as 2.4 Ang. That interlayer spacing is much smaller than the parabolic region, which I would expect at 4-5 Ang  (depending on the force field). I imagine you could increase the multiplier on a3 to nearer 2 and then it might start making sense. for graphite. Equally, for graphene that value should probably be bigger still?
